# I want to store the сustomer information in an array of customers

Tags: c, arrays

this for adding new costumer.

```
typedef struct date{

int d,m,y;

}date;


typedef struct client{

int *id;
char *nom [30];
char *prenom [30];
date date;
char  *adresse[30] ;
char *tel [30];

 }client;
client cl;
    void ajouter (){
        int age;

    printf("give first name:\n");
    scanf("%s",&cl.nom);
    printf("give last name:\n");
    scanf("%s",&cl.prenom);
    printf("give adresse:\n");
    scanf("%s",&cl.adresse);
    printf("give tel num:\n");
    scanf("%s",&cl.tel);
    printf("give date of birth :\n");
    scanf("%d %d %d",&cl.date.d, &cl.date.m, &cl.date.y);

    cl.id=1;
   if(2019-cl.date.y<18)
    printf("refuse");
    else
        printf("                          succes\n");
        printf("your informations:\n");
        printf(" first name: %s \n last name: %s \n adresse: %s \n tel num: %s \n date of birth : %d/%d/%d \n ID: 0000000%d",cl.nom,cl.prenom,cl.adresse,cl.tel,cl.date.d,cl.date.m,cl.date.y,cl.id);
        cl.id++;
    }
```

the problem is when i add the 1st costumer  i dont know how to store the informations
i want to save it without using files.
i am beginner and i know maybe its wrong what am doing
but am trying to do my best to make this code

```
int main()
    {
int a,age;
char t[100];
printf("----------- menu ------------\n");

printf("add  customer : 1\n");

printf("remove customer : 2\n");
    printf("search for customer : 3\n");
        scanf("%d",&a);
    switch(a){
   case(1):ajouter(a);break;

    }

return 0;
    }
```

i didnt finish it yet

Comment: If not files, where do you want to save that information?

Comment: How is the title of this question helpful to anyone?

Comment: A key mistake is not enabling all warnings.  `char *nom [30]; ... scanf("%s",&cl.nom);` should have warned.  Wisely using your compiler is the first step in improving coding efficiency - faster than SO.

Comment: Usually people store data like this in a database, which at some point is a file. You can use a serverless DB like noSQL if you don't want to dive in to DBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salut,

If I understood well, you wish to store a client's data in an array in RAM.
I believe you are using C, hence vectors are not really an option.
So instead, you have either the option of having an array of fixed size, which could be useful in certain situations but generally not, or having a dynamic array, which can be kind of hard to understand when begginning but you shouldn't have much trouble.
In the case a fixed-size array works for you, here's an example of how you'd do it:

```
//Declaring the client array
#define nClientsTableau 100
int nClients = 0;
client clients[nClientsTableau];
...
//Adding a new client, keep in mind it's just an example
ajouter();
clients[nClients] = cl;
nClients++;
if(nClients == nClientsTableau) printf("Max amount of clients reached");
```

Then for the second option, building a dynamic array. Different ways of doing it exist, here is a simple way to perform it for your code:

```
//Declaring the client array
client* clients = NULL;
client* clients2 = NULL;
int nClients = 0

//Adding a new client
ajouter();
nClients++;

clients2 = (client*)realloc(clients, nClients * sizeof(client));

clients = clients2; //NOTE: You should probably check for clients2 not being NULL first
clients[nClients - 1] = cl;

//Ending the program
free(clients);
```

I sincerely hope this helps. Apart from that, I'd like to tell you that your code is excellent for a beginner, just try having some naming conventions.